# Show that a line is tangent to a circle in the extended complex plane.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, complex-numbers

The straight line $l$ in the extended-complex plane pasess through $2+i,2+2i$.The circle $C$ centered at $-1-2i$ with radius $3$.

First, I find the parametrization of the straight line which is
$$z = 2+i+t(2+2i-(2+i))=2+i+it,t\in \mathbb{R}$$
Then the line perpendicular to this line should be
$$z = 2+i+it(i)=2+i-t$$
So the line should contain the centre of the circle 
$$-1-2i=2+i-t$$
But this equation has no solution. So which part I do it wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with “*the* line perpendicular to this line”. There are multiple lines perpendicular to a given line. You chose one through one of the two defining points, but that's an arbitrary choice.

Instead, I'd explicitely take the line through the center. If your original line has direction $i$, one perpendicular direction is $i\cdot i=-1$, so the line perpendicular to your given line and passing through the center of the circle can be described as

$$ -1-2i-u,\quad u\in\mathbb R $$

Now you have two lines, which you can intersect:

\begin{align*}
-1-2i-u &= 2+i+it \\
0 &= 3+3i+it+u
\end{align*}

From this you can read (since $t$ and $u$ must be real) that $t=u=-3$ and the point of tangency, if it exists, is $2-2i$. Now all you have to do is check the distance between that point and the center of the circle.

Comment: Since the distance is exactly same magnitude with the radius this proves that the point must be lie on the circle right? I got your idea, really thanks a lot!